# How to add constraints programmaticaly to xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I have cell with 3 labels. Labels have constraints to cell and to other labels. If I remove Label2 from superview then I will lost constraints and my cell will be changed. How to add constraints between Label1 and Label3 programmatically when I remove Label2.
[image: Cell]

Comment: IO9 + Rock & roll with UIStackView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two Options

1) Use `UIStackView` (**MUST BE IOS9 +**)

2) Constraints

as `UIStackView` answer is already given so I am suggesting you a 2nd way to do it

Similar I have implemented for horizontal aligned label

Follow the steps

1) Let's Say your label is L1, L2, L3 , Give Equal Height to each Label (Please drag L2, And L3 to L1 and give equal Height)

2) Set Equal Height constraint priority to **999**

3) As in your case L2 is optional (May be hidden or removed as per your scenario) so give **HEIGHT**  Constraint to **L2**  with constant **0** with priority **750** (**YOUR CONSTRAINTS NEVER BREAK** )

4) Take **IBOutlet** of  that constraint

5) And give leading trailing top bottom whatever you need in my case it is 0

6) Now You just need to change priority whenever you need to show hide that label

```
 func setupViewForMyMemoriams (){
        self.priority_Width_L2.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
       // OR
       self.priority_Width_L2.priority  = UILayoutPriorityRequired
 }
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Use UIStackView then it will automatically adjust the height.

Another way is not remove the Label2, but make the height become 0, wrap Label2 in an UIView that have height from top Label2 to Label3, then change the height of that UIView to 0, visually it will be Label2 got removed